# How to control visiblity of (fx:)included from controller

Tags: javafx

I have 3 fxml files:

```
Main.fxml
Menu.fxml
Manager.fxml
```

and controller for each.
I need to controll `BorderPane` center of `Main.fxml`from both remaining, so I `fx:include`'d them, gave them `fx:id` and also set included element `Manager.fxml` `visible = false` (only menu button set Manager to center of `BorderPane` ) but now I'am lost and dont understand how to set included fxml visible when button in `Menu.fxml`is pressed. Easy when its about simple element but dont work same with included fxml file.

At the beginning I had only menu inlcuded in `Main.fxml` and method `setCenter` in its controller that i used to switch center element using `MenuController.java` but then i couldn't find way to set main center using manager (so manager could be swithched with other one) becouse FXMLloader only loaded Main and Menu so couldnt set proper MainController instance in ManagerController.

My code before change:

```
public class MainAdminController {

    @FXML
    private AdminMenuController adminMenuController;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane adminBorderPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        adminMenuController.setMainController(this);
    }

    public void setView(String fxmlPatch){
        adminBorderPane.setCenter(Fxml.loadFXML(fxmlPatch));
    } 
}
```

AdminMenuController

```
public class AdminMenuController {
    public static final String MANAGE_ACCOUNTS = "/fxml/admin/ManageAccounts.fxml";
    public static final String MANAGE_ADMINS = "/fxml/admin/ManageAdmins.fxml";
    public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD = "/fxml/ChangePassword.fxml";

    @FXML
    private MainAdminController mainAdminController;

    public void setMainController(MainAdminController mainAdminController) {
        this.mainAdminController = mainAdminController;
    }

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup adminButtons;

    @FXML
    public void viewManageAccounts() {
        mainAdminController.setView(MANAGE_ACCOUNTS);
    }

    @FXML
    public void viewManageAdmins() {
        mainAdminController.setView(MANAGE_ADMINS);
    }

    @FXML
    public void viewChangePassword() {
        mainAdminController.setView(CHANGE_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` when you load, e.g., `ManageAdmins.fxml`, and then basically do the same thing: pass the main controller to the controller for that FXML file.

Comment: @James_D only then I cannot use (my own) static method `Fxml.loadFXML(fxmlPatch)`, am I right?

Comment: At a minimum you'd have to change it so that it passed the main controller to the controller it got from loading the FXML file.